# Scanning file once and cutting different things from it?

Tags: bash, unix

I want to extract information from two columns of textfile. Currently I have my code extracting this information with 3 different scans:

```
cut -d',' -f 8 file1.csv | sort -g | uniq -c | wc -l
cut -d',' -f 9 file1.csv | sort -g | uniq -c | wc -l
cut -d',' -f8,9 file1.csv | sort -g | uniq -c | wc -l
```

I would like to do it all scanning the file only once. I also forgot to add that I would like to get the 3 different line counts, not all combined into one. Is this possible to do somehow without writing a complex program?

Any help appreciated,

Ted.

Comment: What are you wanting as output?

Comment: Three lines, each line containing one number.  That's what the sample code produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `awk` or `perl` (and Python or Ruby could be used instead) to post-process the last variant of `cut`:

```
cut -d',' -f8,9 file1.csv |
awk -F, '{ field8[$1] = 1; field9[$2] = 1; field89[$1,$2] = 1; }
         END {
             i=0; for (j in field8)  { i++; }; print i;
             i=0; for (j in field9)  { i++; }; print i;
             i=0; for (j in field89) { i++; }; print i;
             }'
```

Or, simplifying since `awk` can split fields:

```
awk -F, '{ field8[$8] = 1; field9[$9] = 1; field89[$8,$9] = 1; }
         END {
             i=0; for (j in field8)  { i++; }; print i;
             i=0; for (j in field9)  { i++; }; print i;
             i=0; for (j in field89) { i++; }; print i;
             }' file1.csv
```

Since the question assumes there are no complications with commas embedded in data fields, etc, this answer ignores the issues too.  Be aware, though, that CSV files in general can be too complex to process using simple tools like `cut` (and even `awk`).  Perl has modules to handle CSV properly; so do other extensible scripting languages.

Comment: Are these modules you speak of as fast as using cut and awk?

Comment: Yes - if only because they don't need a pipe to relay the cut information between processes.  The Text::CSV_XS module (using C code to support CSV - instead of using pure Perl) is going to be pretty much as fast as `awk` on its own (and possibly faster), with the added benefit of being correct when the CSV data has fields with embedded commas in them.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F, '
    { a8[$8]; a9[$9]; a89[$8 FS $9] }
    END {
        c=0; for (e in a8)  c++; print "col 8: "   c
        c=0; for (e in a9)  c++; print "col 9: "   c
        c=0; for (e in a89) c++; print "col 8,9: " c
    }
'
```